# Display Text Label Along a Polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering how one might add text that outputs along the edge of a polyline in Google Maps. I can't find any documentation on how to do this, yet have seen it done before.

Also the new Google Maps ski runs have this text affect!
example: http://goo.gl/maps/pbokL

Currently I use the MarkerWithLabel libary to add rectangular labels to the start of a polyline. http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/reference.html
This library doesn't have the functionality I seek.

Comment: I still have not found a solution too this :( Sucks that Google does it internally on their maps, but doesn't not provide the functionality via the API.

Comment: Leaflet-js does this via this plugin (https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath/blob/gh-pages/leaflet.textpath.js). Basically he creates an SVG textpath element. But in Google Maps API, I don't know how you would bind this element to a polyline path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: ELabel.js for Google Maps API V3
https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel

Comment: It appears this just creates rectangular shaped labels. I don't see anything in the source code that says otherwise. I already use another label plugin that does the same thing.