# label within Polyline Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, text, google-maps-api-3

I want to do something similar in google maps api V3...
is this possible? I really appreciate the help as I have no experience with google maps

**Update:**
I want add label for our own polyline like this.

[image: label]
<sub>(source: [aerodromoschile.com](http://www.aerodromoschile.com/Captura.png))</sub>

Comment: I posted the same question last August, I still have not found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089543/display-text-label-along-a-polyline

Answer (score -3):

Im not sure if you can do it exactly like this, but alternatively, you can add there google.maps.marker, save the location to the marker´s title, and add listener on hover/click to display this title.